# get rows by date regardless of format of date in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data as follows:

```
Col1,ColDate
a,2020-09-11 08:43:00
b,2020-09-12 09:43:00
c,13-09-2020 09:43:00
d,09/16/2020 10:43:00
e,09/19/2020 12:43:00
f,09/12/2020 15:43:00
```

Intention is to get all rows between 11th sep and 13th sept, regardless of the format. In pandas

I am trying the following:

```
df[df["ColDate"].between('11-09-2020','13-09-2020')]
```

I get an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

```
 df[pd.to_datetime(df['ColDate']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y').between('11-09-2020','13-09-2020')]

   Col1              ColDate
0    a  2020-09-11 08:43:00
1    b  2020-09-12 09:43:00
2    c  13-09-2020 09:43:00
5    f  09/12/2020 15:43:00
```

but its really hard to say which will be considered month and day, because of the date format being jumbled.

Comment: Thanks. This works. if i have only one date, what should i use instead of `between`?

Comment: That one date is upper bound or lower bound?

Comment: sorry. i meant it should belong to a particular day

Comment: You can use `.gt`,  `.lt`  , `.eq` and similar accessors. They all work with dates.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html, if you look the menu, you can find others.

Comment: @Bharath is there a way to exclude date 13 from it?

Comment: @Karthik by default `.between` has `inclusive=True`, if you set that to false you can exclude the boundaries.

Comment: @Bharath True. But this will exclude date 11 also . I was just thinking to exclude 13

Comment: @Karthik, then its not possible with `.between`. We have to go with logical operators like in your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, happy new year! :-)

Comment: @cs95 Happy new year! and I really liked the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Please Check the snippet. You can first convert your **Coldate** to `pd.to_datetime` format and then you can apply a mask over it like this.

```
df['ColDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColDate'])
mask = (df['ColDate'] > '2020-09-11') & (df['ColDate'] <='2020-09-13')
df = df.loc[mask]
```

```
Output
  Col1             ColDate
0    a 2020-09-11 08:43:00
1    b 2020-09-12 09:43:00
5    f 2020-09-12 15:43:00
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but how can i use the `dd-mm-yyyy format`? And also one line command would be more useful